# Keycloak container failing to start in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, keycloak-services

I am trying to set up keycloak in Kubernetes and facing below error  saying "SC000001: Failed to start service org.wildfly.network.interface.private: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in                    service org.wildfly.network.interface.private: WFLYSRV0082: failed to resolve interface private".

I added below parameters to deployment.yaml file
[image]

I still see same error.
[image]